# How can we select text of settings window

Tags: macos

I frequently encounter situations where I need to describe certain issues. During these descriptions, I find myself needing to provide details about the system settings. This requires me to repeatedly write out the lengthy settings name or options.

Is there a method or setting available that allows me to conveniently select and extract the text from the native [macOS system settings windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QSFc.png), such as the one shown in the image below?

Answer (score 1):

Since **macOS Monterey** you can screenshot a window (`Cmd`+`Shift`+`4`, `Space`), click in the floating miniature before it’s saved in the *Desktop*, and just select the text from the screenshot.

Apple calls that “Live Text” and it also works in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

One method that would work on almost any OS:

- Take a screen shot.
- Use [optical character recognition (OCR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) to "scrape" data from the image.

  There are free online OCR services, such as [OnlineOCR](https://www.onlineocr.net/) and [NewOCR](https://www.onlineocr.net/).

  There are [free OCR applications](https://www.cisdem.com/resource/online-free-ocr-tools-mac.html) for the Mac OS.

On a Windows box, I made a test of printing data from a Services dialog using [FreeOCR](http://www.freeocr.net/) and the two online services above, and was pleasantly surprised at near 100% accuracy (one service had some extra characters).